# Android Studio Magnets

Tags: android, android-studio, radio-button, android-constraintlayout

hey guys anybody knows how to cook two radio buttons to aling together coardantly in a single line?

[image]

i tried magnets and constrain layouts, It didn't work.

Comment: You need to describe what you actually want-  "coordantly" isn't a word, and I'm not quite sure what you are looking for.  Also, post the xml of your layout-  we need that to actually tell how you're trying to do things.

Answer (score 0):

In constraint Layout
you can add constraints to your female RadioButton

app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/male"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/male"

or by right click on the Female RadioButton, then show baseline, it will show you a bar inside the radio button drag to the baseline of the male RadioButton
then constrain the start to the end male RadioButton